# Chart JS tooltip label not showing correct value

Tags: java, chart.js, label, gson, tooltip

I'm working on a Java project , we create our charts with ChartJs using GsonBuilder.
My JSON looks like this :

```
 {
      "data": {
        "datasets": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "x": "05/12/2022 07:00:00",
                "y": "1",
                "value": "value A"
              },
              {
                "x": "05/13/2022 14:08:00",
                "y": "1",
                "value": "value B"
              }
            ],
            "label": "Bacteria",
            "borderColor": "#a1c450",
            "yAxisID": "Values",
          }
        ]
      },
      "options": {
        "plugins": {
          "tooltip": {
            "mode": "single",
            "callbacks": {
              "label": "function(tooltipItem, data) {return tooltipItem.value;}"
            },
            "enabled": true
          }
        },
        "scales": {
          "yAxes": [
            {
              "scaleLabel": {
                "labelString": "Values",
                "display": false
              },
              "display": false,
              "id": "Values",
              "position": "right"
            }
          ],
          "xAxes": [
            {
              "display": true,
              "type": "time"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "type": "scatter"
    }
```

Instead of showing "Value A/B" the tooltip is shows "x,y" of the corresponding data item.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Nvy.png)

I've tried returning `data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].value;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using V2 of Chart.js while using V3 syntax for the tooltip. This wont work. The options for the tooltip in V2 are placed in a different location:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
          x: 0.2505597250394178,
          y: 12
        },
        {
          x: 0.1629651642029184,
          y: 19
        },
        {
          x: 0.6825862858121792,
          y: 3
        },
        {
          x: 0.39821027356939087,
          y: 5
        },
        {
          x: 0.1088502186196103,
          y: 2
        },
        {
          x: 0.7836566822098099,
          y: 3
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (ttItem) => (ttItem.value)
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```